# Optimizing over an infinite set of variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

This may be a very basic question, but it's been a while since I did any optimization.

Suppose I have a sequence $(x_i)$, $i=1,2,\ldots$ in the $\ell^2$ space and the following optimization problem:

$$\underset{\{x_i\}}{\operatorname{minimize}}\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)\\
\text{subject to}~\sum_{i=1}^\infty g(x_i)\leq C$$

Functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are diffirentiable and convex. Can I still use the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) here?  If so, are there any additional steps that I need to take, such as showing certain properties for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

When I perform the standard steps, differentiating Lagrangian functional $\Lambda=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i)+\lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty g(x_i)-C\right)$ with respect to each $x_i$, and solving each $\frac{\partial\Lambda}{\partial x_i}=0$, I can show that the solution $(x_i^*)$ results in the converging objective function: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i^*)>-\infty$ and that $\lambda\geq0$ exists such that the constraint is satisfied.  Is there anything more I need to do?

Comment: how do you ensure the convergence of these series?

Comment: @user251257 I obtain a functional form for $x_i^*$ (it turns out to be a function of some constant parameters that define $f(x)$ and $g(x)$) and substitute into the objective function and the constraint.  I obtain convergence by standard tests -- integral test, with the integral converging by a limit test. (note, there were two typos: minor one in the convergence statement for the objective function, and a bigger one -- the constraint is an inequality).

Comment: well, you need $\lambda \ge 0$ if you have inequality. I am not convinced that the problem is well-defined. In which space is the sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$?

Comment: @user251257 $x_i$'s are real numbers ($x_i^*$'s come out positive, which makes sense withing the greater scope of the problem).  I can show that $\lambda\geq0$ exists that satisfies the constraint (I updated the question).

Comment: It is hard to say without more details. Usually if you have frechet differentiability, then Lagrange multiplier works basically like in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @user251257 Could you please elaborate on the "if you have frechet diifferentiability, then Lagrange multiplier works basically like in $\mathbb{R}^n$?  I think you might be talking about the calculus of variations, which I don't know at all (I would like to start learning it though).  Perhaps you could point out to me *what* needs to be frechet differentiable for me to use Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Google for "Lagrange multiplier Banach space". I am not an expert for that matter either. The mapping $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N} \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f(x_i)$ and $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N} \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} g(x_i)$ should be frechet differentiable (or even more). If your problem is convex, you might be able to weaken some of these smoothness conditions.

Comment: @user251257 Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are convex, which makes my problem convex.  They are also differentiable, which, I believe, makes sums Frechet-differentiable (though I am not sure about that). I've updated the question once again. Seems like this isn't as elementary as thought it would be...

Comment: just the differentiability of $f$ and $g$ are differentiable does not implies the differentiability of the series. Therefore I have asked you which space the sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is an element of. Some $\ell^p$? In infinite dimensional spaces such details are important.

Comment: @user251257 Ahh.  Thinking about this deeper, $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is in the $\ell^2$ space.  I'll update my question.